# Is there only one solution to the "Ten Penny Puzzle" or more?

Tags: mathematics, geometry, optimization, packing

Not knowing the dimensions of the square in the [Ten Penny Puzzle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I-SpRl-AxI0) I ask if there is more than one unique solution that isn't a reflection/mirror of the one shown in the video, if you know the dimensions of the square of course. Perhaps more interestingly though, I want to ask what if we have ten unit circles, then vary the bounding square around it from having a side length, $s$, of $3$ units ($s\in\mathbb{R}$) to see the minimum side length it takes greater than $3$ units to generate a solution (possibly not singularly unique). Also, how many unique solutions exist in the range $s\in(3,4)$?

The puzzle involves fitting 10 pennies into the square shown without overlapping:

[image: Ten Penny Puzzle]

Comment: Could you include a full description of the puzzle in your question so that we don't have to watch the video?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With regards to the uniqueness of the solution:

> The solution to the puzzle shown in the video is the most optimal packing of 10 circles in a square, so assuming that the dimensions of the puzzle are tight enough, then the solution is unique.
>  For a proof of optimality of that solution, you can read the following paper:
>  [**The Optimal Packing of Ten Equal Circles in a Square**
> by *Claas de Groot, Ronald Peikert, and Diethelm Würtz*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228327432_The_Optimal_Packing_of_Ten_Equal_Circles_in_a_Square)

For other solutions:

> You can see (near) optimal packings with other numbers of circles on the [Circle packing in a square Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_square). By leaving out some of the circles in the solutions with 11-15 circles you get lots of possibilities for packing 10 circles in a square of size $s<4d$ where $d$ is the circle diameter.